# Datatable freeze during change show entries

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have like below:
[image: after change show entries datatable no response]
After I have changed show entries to 25 in datatable, the datatable seems no response. Its just show `processing` inside datatable body.

This the server side script for show entries:

```
$sLimit = "";
        if ( isset( $_POST['iDisplayStart'] ) )
        {
                $sLimit = " LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
                        mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['iDisplayLength'] );
        }
```

why its happen? how to fix that?
Exactly I have two datatables inside this page.I put them in different tabs.

[Datatable script](http://pastebin.com/emzG7cri)

[html table](http://pastebin.com/RTLdudng)

[serverside script](http://pastebin.com/nVjZN4EE)

---

The trouble come during show `range` column but if not use this column all can work properly.the query like:

```
$sQuery = "SELECT DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date, A.Line, A.Model, 
                                  A.Lot_no,A.Range_sampling,COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Error,B.name AS PIC
                           FROM inspection_report A
                           LEFT JOIN Employee B
                           ON A.NIK=B.NIK
                           WHERE CHAR_LENGTH( A.Range_sampling ) < 17
                           AND MONTH(A.Inspection_datetime)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)" .$sWhere.$sGroupBy.$sOrder.$sLimit;
```

Whether `CHAR_LENGTH` is the root cause? exactly this problem only occurs on the database a server for a local computer everything goes well.why?

Comment: can you dump the whole query and post it? there must be an error somewhere..

Comment: I think the error is on your Grid. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: @all: I have dumped all script, please check it.

Comment: `fnCallback(json);`, which is called in your script, isn't defined anywhere. Consider adding a `console.log()` or `alert()` call before it to see if the ajax succeeded at all (in which case it's the culprit), and if so, paste its definition too.

Comment: @Denis:I add alert(json) after success, then show alert `[object Object]`.

Comment: Cool, so you now know where to look for a js error (i.e., in the callback you pass as an argument).

Comment: @Denis: sorry, I have no knowledge in this plugin. could you tell me how should I do after show this alert?

Comment: Neither do I, to be honest. I'm merely pointing out, that the error is not on your server. It's on whichever method you're passing (or gets passed by default) to the plugin so it knows what to do with the data. The error occurs after the data retrieval. Try console.log(fnCallback) to see its definition in Firebug, Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @Denis: that is the strange point of this problem. no problem found in console( no error). This datatable can work after I delete `range` column. but if use `range` column trouble happen.Whether datatable is confuse during I want to show some complicated query( I think my query no problem in MySQL and not too complicated).

Comment: try to console.dir(json) and look at what it says. Maybe the data in the range column is malformed and it stops because the json is not totally valid

Comment: not show anything.just show result as ussual.

Comment: Then I try to download the latest DataTable but still not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. In the fnServerData handler, you can read aoData[0].value to get the 'sEcho' value. This values needs to be assigned to the sEcho property of the json object you pass to your datatable.

The expected type for sEcho is also a string and you are converting to an integer.

```
$sOutput .= '"sEcho": '.intval($_POST['sEcho']).',';
```

try just

`$sOutput .= '"sEcho": "'. $_POST['sEcho'] .'" ,';`